# how to fix this error in a laravel project "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: laravel, server-error

I created a laravel project in a another pc and zipped it without the node modules and vendor folder. And I started working on another pc and installed the node modules and the vendor files and this error is getting after that.

I was searching through the web but didn't find anything usefull

Comment: Check your MySQL server is running. (Xampp, LAMP). And check your DB access is correct in `.env`. make sure you ran `php artisan optimize` after config change

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular reason for this error. you can try to check out the following checklist.

1. check server is running properly.
2. check if the firewall is blocking the port or service
3. check your login details are valid.
4. check your network is reachable from the web server to the database server.

These steps should fix your issue.